Distributing pythonnet dll type information in pip package
I've been able to load a C# dll using pythonnet by using the following:
from importlib.resources import path
import sys

# Assuming 'my_package.lib' is the sub-package containing the DLLs
with path('pyrp.lib', '') as lib_path:
    sys.path.append(str(lib_path))

# Now you can import your dependencies as if they were in the same directory
from pythonnet import load
load('coreclr')
import clr

def load_APIStandard():
    clr.AddReference("myDLL")
    from myDLL import APIStandard

    # Return the imported module or any objects you need from it
    return APIStandard

and I have the type information generated with this tool. One example is
#__init__.pyi
from System import Array_1
from myDLL import AnalysisResult

class APIStandard(abc.ABC):
    @staticmethod
    def AnalyzeData(data: Array_1[int]) -> AnalysisResult: ...

I can get this type information to display properly if edit my VSCode settings.json
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
      "./pyrp/lib/PythonTypes" // Add the path to your "types" directory here, adjust the path as necessary
    ]

but no matter how I package the types into the pip package, I can't get the interpreter to find them natively. Any suggestions?

What do you mean by "interpreter to find them natively"? You say that interpreter finds the library implementation just fine. Pyi stub files are only for static analysis tools (mypy, pyright, vscode language server, whatever) - they are not used at run time.

Sorry, I thought the selected interpreter was also used for parsing the language definition. Perhaps it's a terminology problem, I just mean VSCode (Pylance?) isn't able to find the types (although this does change for packages depending on if I have the correct interpreter selected)

If I understand your problem correctly, you've hit one of the few python quirks where naming is important. Stub package for library pythonnet should be called pythonnet-stubs to be detected automatically, see PEP-561 and this QA, and you'll need to really install it as far as I understand, or just stick with explicit reference you already have. (I don't use VSCode and can't help debug this further, sorry)

No worries, thanks for the help. I'm abandoning for now and just going to distribute source :(... maybe I'll have time to come back to it later

Ah, so you're the developer of that library? Then things are easier, at least you can distribute the stub package result! Or look at how numpy does that in the same package (basically .pyi files alongside library code): https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/main/numpy (py.typed marker at the package root is the important part)

(you don't necessarily need .py files corresponding to .pyi files, that's just how numpy works, .pyi overrides .py - type checkers don't look for such .py files)
